# Weird screeching sounds coming from computer

Tags: memory, ssd, audio

My computer makes a high pitched whine noise that initially was coming from my SSD, but now I recently installed more ram into my laptop and it makes a new sounds. I don't want my ram or SSD to die on me. Are there any tests to test both of these?

Again, these are really high pitched whine(y) sounds that you wouldn't hear normally, but when I'm home alone and it's silent, the noise sounds as loud as can be.

Comment: SSD's and RAM have no moving parts.  If this is a whining sound, my first guess is that it is a fan whose bearings have gone south on you.  An even more rare possibility is a "singing" capacitor, but those are usually of a constant pitch and intensity.

Comment: Call an exorcist.

Comment: My laptop fans are not creating the sound, because they are not spinning most of the time. In the case of my monitor, I don't have one/this computer is a laptop.

Comment: Did you ever consider that it's the non-spinning causing the problem? I'd just be safe and take it to a repair person.

Comment: They mostly don't spin because it isn't hot. Latest i5 doesn't set the fan off until I play games on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the screen inverter.  The fluorescent lamp that illuminates your laptop screen requires AC power.  The inverter converts the DC power from your battery (or power supply) to AC.  When the inverter fails, it often produces a whining noise.

Comment: Is there any way to check that? I heard the noise again today and it seem to be coming from between the 'g' and 'h' keys on my keyboard. That's right where my ram was installed.